# "How do I use a variable in plpgpsql in a where clause?"

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

I have a function created in plpgsql. The function has a cursor called CURSOR_ and while I fetch the values of  the cursor, a query is performed inside the loop. My query uses a where condition with data from the cursor. The problem is that the variable **name_var** always is empty when the function perform the query, in spite of it changes with values retrieved from the cursor. What am I doign wrong?.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_return_company_centers()  RETURNS 
TABLE(company text, centers text) AS
$BODY$

DECLARE CURSOR_ CURSOR FOR SELECT C.NAME, M.LOCATION || '__' || M.STORAGEKEY AS CENTER
                   FROM COMPANY C INNER JOIN MONITOR M ON C.ID = M.COMPANY_ID
                   ORDER BY C.NAME;
v_parent_rec RECORD;
name_var text :='';
_CENTROS text := '';
POS int := 0;

BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TMP_COMPANY_CENTER (company text, centers text);
    DELETE FROM TMP_COMPANY_CENTER;

    FOR v_parent_rec IN CURSOR_  LOOP
        IF name_var = '' THEN
            name_var := v_parent_rec.name; 

            SELECT A.CENTROS INTO _CENTROS 
            FROM SCHEDULER_REPORT A
            WHERE A.EMPRESA = name_var ;

            POS := position(v_parent_rec.center in _CENTROS);
            RAISE NOTICE 'Es %', POS; 
    END LOOP;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM TMP_COMPANY_CENTER ORDER BY COMPANY;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Thnks in advance,

Daniel.

Comment: Unrleated, but: running a select statement inside a cursor loop is always a bad choice. That will have a *terrible* performance. (I'm pretty sure the whole function can be reduced to a single statement - without a cursor or a loop or a temporary table if you tell us what the *real* problem is you want to solve here)  You are also not inserting any rows into your temp table, so the result of that function will always be empty.

Comment: have you verified that the v_parent_rec variable is being assigned a value? i would recommend printing your variables to the console output with a raise notice in order to help you step through the code and determine where the error is occurring.

Comment: Ok I have resolved it. Thanks.